# How to use Boost uBLAS C++ library in an iPhone project?

Tags: c++, iphone, boost, ublas

I want to use Boost library in my iPhone project, specifically only boost::numeric::ublas. I managed to build static libraries for boost in order to link them in my iPhone project. However, when I look at those .a libraries I can't find one that's related to ublas (I tried ./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=ublas in terminal but no luck). Does anyone know which static library to look for ublas? Or how to use ublas in an iPhone project in general?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't answer the iPhone-specific part but I can help at least with the Boost part...

Boost uBlas is a header-only library so you don't need to build and link against any .a files. Just include the headers in your project if you want to use the library.

Answer (score 2):

uBlas is header-only so there is no static library - see this view of the libraries:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/?view=filtered_header-only

Answer (score 2):

If you are OK with running iOS4 only, use the Accelerate framework, it has BLAS and features hardware acceleration (when available, software otherwise).

Even if you need 3.x support, it would be worth figuring out how to toggle the use of Accelerate when possible just to get the hardware support.

Comment: Yes, from the benchmarks I've seen, Accelerate is much faster than many of the stock implementations of these vector operations.